# Populating HTML 'select' drop down using sql array - Code not working

Tags: php, html, sql, arrays, drop-down-menu

I am using the below code to take each individual value out of an array returned by an sql query. When the page runs, the dropdown box is populated by the correct number of spaces. 4 at the moment. However, there is no information in those spaces. The drop down box is simply populated by 4 blank spaces. Any ideas??

```
Date Selection:
        <select name="dateselection">

        <?php

            $i = 0;
            while ($i < $num)
            {
                $thedate = mysql_result(results, $i, 'date');

                ?>

                <option> <?php echo $thedate; ?> </option>>



                <?php


                $i++;
            }

        ?>

        </select>
```

Comment: You _really_ need to start looking at your error logs - you would've been able to solve this in seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed a dollar sign:

```
$thedate = mysql_result(results, $i, 'date');
                        ^-- HERE
```

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that for last 30 mins. Sorry to waste your time, and thanks very much!!

Comment: I would suggest you set your error reporting to E_ALL, that code would've generated a warning which would allow you to spot it directly  :)